# How can I extends a Modal in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, oop, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

Firstly, I have a problem with OOP in javascript, and I understand very little about this, but I need to solve the problem...

Well, I am trying use, on Bootstrap 4, a library made for Bootstrap 3: https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog

I get the following error: "Cannot call a class as a function"

Looking the code, I discovered somethings:

1 - classCallCheck: is the function that throws the error. I suppose that it forces the user use "new" and instantiate an object and never call like a function;

2 - createClass: is a function that constructs classes, so the classes in Bootstrap 4 is not defined conventionally.

3 - inherits: is another function and shows that the inheritance is not conventional too.

4 - The library has this code to extends the Bootstrap Modal:

```
var BootstrapDialogModal = function (element, options) {
    Modal.call(this, element, options);
};
```

But, Modal.call trigger the error: "Cannot call a class as a function".

I suppose the only problem is BootstrapDialogModal inherits Modal in inheritance conditions imposed by Bootstrap 3 and, when Bootstrap 4 is active, these conditions are not the same.

Follow a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g6nrnvwu/

Someone know how can I adjust this code?

Thanks.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is a huge update/remake from Bootstrap 3. This happen because (maybe) there's a conflicting new class name in bootstrap 4 called "Modal". You can try to change all function which named "Modal" inside that library with another name. Maybe it'll work, except there's still more conflicts. Better use another alternative library or make yourself (because I do it and I'm sure less 3rd party library come to faster page load) ._.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: You get the following error "Cannot call a class as a function" because you really cannot use class as a function. In Bootstrap 4 Modal is a class, and if the plugin is using base Modal class, it should extend it. I recommend you to forget about using such combination because you cannot just fix it with few lines (also considering that Modal was reworked on path to Bootstrap 4). Your question can be solved in direct way only by rewriting the Plugin completely))

Comment: @NavjotAhuja follow the link to JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g6nrnvwu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at this pull request that aims to update the plugin to BS 4: https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/pull/281/files?diff=unified

Answer (score 1):

Ok it's not exactly an answer, but an example that maybe can help you. This is a class i made to handle modal dynamically inserting it's markup on the fly. It's not BS4 but you can use as a guide maybe?

[ModalUtils](https://github.com/marcoiai/modal)